# Running Total Referencing Multiple Columns Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a (hopefully simple) question. I am trying to create a running total in Python using Pandas. Say I have workers, who each day track their hours worked. I would like to know the running total, reported each day, of how many hours they have worked thus far.

Say I have a Pandas Dataframe, with four columns, like such (added horizontal space between days for easier reading):

```
  Day Worker HoursWorked HoursWorkedThusFar
   1      1           0                  0
   1      2           2                  0
   1      3           4                  0

   2      1           6                  0
   2      2           8                  0
   2      3          10                  0

   3      1          12                  0
   3      2          14                  0
   3      3          16                  0
```

I would like to fill out the "HoursWorkedThusFar" column. Note that each worker starts the week having worked zero hours.

In very rough psuedocode, I would like to do the following for the HoursWorkedThusFar column:

```
For Day 2 onward:
    For each worker:
        Add up previous day's work, plus previous day's hours worked thus far
```

So column HoursWorkedThusFar should fill out to be:

```
  Day Worker HoursWorked HoursWorkedThusFar
   1      1           0                   0  (Initial Value)
   1      2           2                   0  (Initial Value)
   1      3           4                   0  (Initial Value)

   2      1           6                   0  (0+0)
   2      2           8                   2  (0+2)
   2      3          10                   4  (0+4)

   3      1          12                   6  (0+6)
   3      2          14                   10 (2+8)
   3      3          16                   14 (4+10)
```

Here is the code to generate that example initial Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Day', 'Worker', 'HoursWorked', 'HoursWorkedThusFar'))
for i in range(3):
   df.loc[i] = [1, i + 1, i*2, 0]
for i in range(3,6):
   df.loc[i] = [2, i - 2, i*2, 0]
for i in range (6,9):
   df.loc[i] = [3, i - 5, i*2, 0]
print(df)
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. You need to convert your column to a numeric type first though.

```
df['HoursWorked'] = df['HoursWorked'].astype(float)


df['HoursWorkedThusFar'] = df.groupby('Worker')['HoursWorked'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift().fillna(0))
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I used df["HoursWorkedThusFar"] = np.where(df['Day'] > 1, df.groupby("Worker")['HoursWorked'].cumsum(), 0) to apply this to only Day 2 onwards.

Comment: I edited my submission to shift the cumsum output down one for each group, then filling the blanks with 0 to get what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`pd.Series.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html?highlight=cumsum#pandas.Series.cumsum) to generate running total

```
# Ordering data by worker and converting to numeric for application of running total
df["HoursWorked"]=df["HoursWorked"].astype(float)
df["HoursThusFar"] = df.groupby("Worker").cumsum()
```

## Breaking it Down

We create the `df["HoursThusFar"]` variable and do the following:

1. We convert the `["HoursWorked"]` to `astype(float)`
2. We call the data frame and `groupby` each by each `"Worker"`
3. We get the `["HoursWorked"]` series to get ready to calculate the running sum
4. We call `cumsum()` method to get running total

Comment: This almost works! I think it needs to have the column 'HoursWorked' to be specified to work properly - otherwise Pandas doesn't know which column should be summed up. See my comment on the other post for how I applied both of your suggestions.